# Groovy hashmap and looping

Tags: groovy

I need to store key value pairs in groovy like for ex, store, address

> key: store abc val: 123 street

> key: store xyz val: north street

How can I achieve this? I tried below

```
 mapAddress = [store:"abc", addr:"123 street"]
 mapAddress.append

 mapAddress = [store:"xyz", addr:"north street"]
 mapAddress.append
```

But it retains only the last record store: xyz.

And how can I loop only the unique stores using for loop? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create a list of maps.
See https://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_map_literals

In your example you just reassign your map with the new value

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to store them in the format you've showed?
I recommend storing them like so:

```
def stores = [:] // define your variable here
stores << ["abc": "123 street"] // first entry
stores << ["xyz": "north street"] // second entry
```

Or if you need to have more data per each store, then you can store them in a map of maps:

```
def stores = [:]
stores << ["abc": [address: "123 street", "some other property": "some value"]]
stores << ["xyz": [address: "north street", "some other property": "some other value"]]
```

Maps can only hold unique keys, so if you add a new entry with the same key as one that's already in the map, the previous entry will be replaced.

In both of the cases you can simply loop through them via
`stores.each{ println(it) }`.

If you plan to have multiple stores that will have the same key, you could store them in a map of lists, for example:

```
def stores = [:]
stores << ["abc": [[address: "123 street", "some other property": "some value"], [address: "456 street", "some other property": "some value"]]]
stores << ["xyz": [[address: "north street", "some other property": "some other value"]]]

stores.each { 
    println it.value.first()
}
```

But, at this point you're probably better off using classes to define your data.